# Javascript/jQuery decrementing an input date with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm am new in the site and new to programming to..
I want to know if there's a way to decrement one day from date picker and put in some field of a form, so farm i could take the server date and decrement, but i need decrement a input date from other field.

Here's what i have so far:

```
$('inp:dateEvent').change(function() {
    var date2 = $('inp:dateEvent').datepicker('getDate', '-1d'); 
    $('dateBeforeEvent').datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```

I already try to change the variables from place, nothing works!

Thanks for the help and sorry if i put the post in the wrong place or something like that.

P.S: If there's a way with sql, could work for me too!

Comment: Here `$('dateBeforeEvent')` didn't you mean a class name ? If it is a class name (such as `<div class="dateBeforeEvent">` ) then you should put a dot before the class name. For example: `$('.dateBeforeEvent')`

Comment: SQL would be `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, OrigDate) AS DecDate`

Comment: No, no.. It's a form field, that a user will put the date using a datepicker..
Unfortunately i still could't find the answer yet anywhere. It's not a date picked form the server but from another datepicker field that is in my form.

anyway thanks for the reply man!

Comment: You can easily accomplish such task, using `moment.js`

Comment: I'll take a look in moment.js!

Comment: I'll try the SQL too, thanks Patrick